# Remove HTML Comment Tags from text

Tags: regex, python-2.7, beautifulsoup

I'm really struggling trying to remove comment tags from HTML.

**I want to keep everything inside the comment tags**. I just want to remove `<!--` and `-->` from the text.

I'm writing code using **Python 2.7** and **BeautifulSoup4**.

I've tried using **Regex** to no avail. I tried the pattern `"(<!--.*?-->)"`, but this seems to remove everything inside also.

I've also tried `"(<!--|-->)"` but it did not do what I wanted.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Can you please provide some actual code you have tried so far ? and also example of texts and strings you are trying to match your regex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use re.sub:

```
import re

f = open('filename.txt', 'r').readlines()
for n in f:
  text = n.rstrip()
othertext = re.sub('<!--', '', text)
f = open('saved.txt', 'a')
f.write(othertext)
f.write('\n')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can Just Group the Comments tag and replace the remaining data in the file

```
import re
List = "C:\\Users\\Administrator\\Desktop\\File1.txt"
with open(List,'r') as readfile:
     content = readfile.readlines()
for i in content:
    if '!' in i :
        line = re.sub('(\<!--)([\w ]*)(-->)',r'\2',i)
        with open('C:\\Users\\Administrator\\Desktop\\File2.txt',"a+") as writefile:
            writefile.write(line)
```